# Split a "tagged" PDF document into multiple documents, keeping the tagging

Tags: pdf, itext

In a project I have to split a PDF document into two documents, one containing all blank pages, and one containing all pages with content.

For this job, I use a ***PdfReader*** to read the source file, and two ***pdfCopy*** objects (one for the blank pages document, one for the pages with content document) to write the files to.

I use ***GetImportedPage*** to read a ***PdfImportedPage***, which is then added to one of the ***PdfCopy*** writers.

Now, the problem is the following: the source file is using the "*tagged PDF format*".  To preserve this (which is absolutely required), I use the ***SetTagged()*** method on both ***PdfCopy*** writers, and use the extra third parameter in ***GetImportedPage(...)*** to keep the tagged format. However, when calling the ***AddPage(...)*** on the ***PdfCopy*** writer, I get an invalid cast exception:

"*Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference'.*"

Anyone has any ideas on how to solve this ? Any hints ?
Also: the project currently refers version 5.1.0.0 of the itext libraries.  In 5.4.4.0 the third parameter to GetImportedPage does not seem to be there anymore.

Below, you can find a code extract:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document targetPdf = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
iTextSharp.text.Document blankPdf = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader sourcePdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputFile);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy targetPdfWriter = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(targetPdf, new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create));
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy blankPdfWriter = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(blankPdf, new FileStream(blanksFile, FileMode.Append));

targetPdfWriter.SetTagged();
blankPdfWriter.SetTagged();

try
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = null;
    int n = sourcePdfReader.NumberOfPages;

    targetPdf.Open();
    blankPdf.Open();

    blankPdf.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase("This document contains the blank pages removed from " + inputFile));
    blankPdf.NewPage();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        byte[] pageBytes = sourcePdfReader.GetPageContent(i);
        string pageText = "";
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser token = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(pageBytes));
        while (token.NextToken())
        {
            if (token.TokenType == iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.TokType.STRING)
            {
                pageText += token.StringValue;
            }
        }

        if (pageText.Length >= 15)
        {
            page = targetPdfWriter.GetImportedPage(sourcePdfReader, i, true);
            targetPdfWriter.AddPage(page);
        }
        else
        {
            page = blankPdfWriter.GetImportedPage(sourcePdfReader, i, true);
            blankPdfWriter.AddPage(page);
            blankPageCount++;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception at LOC1: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The error occurs in the call to ***targetPdfWriter.AddPage(page);*** near the end of the code sample.

Thank you very much for your help.

Koen.

Comment: As far as I can see the third parameter is still there: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html#getImportedPage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader, int, boolean); as a matter of fact, iText 5.4.4 was enhanced with better Tagged PDF functionality for a customer: http://itextpdf.com/release/itext544 The new functionality was tested in cooperation with that customer and the project was accepted. Since you're using iText 5, you probably have a commercial license. Did you contact support to find out what goes wrong?

Comment: Dear Bruno, the parameter is indeed still there - in my tests I used both PDFWriter and PDFCopy, and only the override in PDFCopy has the extra parameter.

Comment: On the subject of the Tagged PDF functionality: I am still executing tests, and whatever I have already tried, the invalid cast exception is always there when AddPage is called.  According to project management, we do have a commercial license, but nothing like a "support contract" or "contact". Groeten.

Comment: The support contract comes with a commercial license. You should have received a request to register 3 users on our internal JIRA ticketing system. The problem you report sounds like a problem caused by a specific PDF (not all PDFs are created equally). We'd need that PDF. The JIRA system is used so that such a PDF can be shared privately.

Comment: Dear Bruno, I have edited my question with a code sample.  Formatting seems to have gone wrong for unknown reasons (more than 4 spaces got chopped off).  I will have to check for support, I'm external to the organisation I am developing for.  I will also have to check if the source PDF can be made available to you. Bedankt, groeten.

Comment: You add a `Phrase` and a `newPage()` to the `Document` used by a `PdfCopy` instance. That's not valid. It will most certainly break the tagged PDF structure.

Comment: For your information, the code extract works fine if we do not have to support the "tagged PDF format".  Without the "SetTagged()" calls on the targetPdfWriter and blankPdfWriter, and without the "true" option for the "GetImportedPage(...)" calls, the routine runs without exceptions, but the tagged format is lost.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, first time failure is for the targetPdfWriter, so it is not related to the extra paragraph in the blankPdf.  I have just tested the code without the adding of the Phrase and the newPage(), and the test confirmed the above: same behaviour.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace (or however that is called in .Net) of the error, preferably using the current iTextSharp. Furthermore (if the stacktrace does not give rise to an obvious explanation of the observed behavior), please supply sample documents to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, I would try to reproduce the problem, but I don't know the first thing about C#, so I depend on the iTextSharp employees. However: (1) today is a holiday in Belgium, and (2) I can't involve employees outside JIRA.

Comment: Bruno, at some places in Belgium, people even work on the 11th of November :-) even though it is a public holiday, indeed.  Since my project manager has taken the day off, I have no access to the contract information concerning the Jira logins.  I will try to get the info to you as soon as possible.

Comment: For your information, here is already the stack trace of the exception: `"   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy.AddPage(PdfImportedPage iPage)\r\n   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy.AddPage(PdfImportedPage iPage)\r\n   at TaggedPDFSplitter.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\Data\\Development\\Local\\TaggedPDFSplitter\\TaggedPDFSplitter\\Program.cs:line 86"`

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Hello Bruno, is there another way to contact you on this matter (email, for example) - I would rather not release internal information from the client where the problem occurs on this public forum.

Comment: You've been contacted by Garry Vleminckx. You can communicate through him to activate your account on our private ticketing system.

Comment: You could always retag the PDF.